# How to get Release google map api key for android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I got lots of answer regarding this question, But i am confused. Actually i have used google map in my android application and created google map api key without entering sha-1 and package name. So it will work in release apk or not?

Thanks for suggest to me.
And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: go to my this answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692005/google-map-reporting-invalid-key-in-android/20696401#comment31009373_20696401](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692005/google-map-reporting-invalid-key-in-android/20696401#comment31009373_20696401) for your all informatin,