# Maps don't show when exported to signed application package

Tags: java, android, maps

My maps do not show when I export into signed application package, and I don't know how to solved it.

Please help me

Comment: have you created new map api key after singing the apk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you'r using google map API then kindly check your map API Key which is mentioned in androidManifest file.

You need to make sure that map API key is being generated for the particular package of your application.

Comment: enjoy coding and use stackoverflow for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

You need make sure that you generated API key with your own keystore. and also check your manifest.xml file contains particular package and go to my this answer for better understanding [Google map reporting invalid key in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692005/google-map-reporting-invalid-key-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have created the API key using your release.keystore . And also please check that you have given the same package name of App in the goggle console while generating map API key .